# Easy way to have my Discord bot read the contents of a webpage?

Tags: node.js, web, https, discord

First time poster and inexperienced coder here. I've wanted to make my Discord bot read the Binding of Isaac wiki to send information such as item descriptions when the user sends a command such as "!effect (itemname)"

Example:

> User: !effect diplopia
> Bot: **Effect:** Duplicates all pickups and pedestal items in the current room, then disappears.

Link used in example: https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Diplopia

I haven't tried too much since I don't know where to start, but I have looked around for quite a bit but it all either seems to complicated for someone of my skill level or unrelated to what I'm trying to do.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to coding! To read an external web page such as https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Diplopia, you would need an HTTP client library. One of the most popular at the moment is [needle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle).

A simple example of how you can the module is is shown below. The link to the npm module above documents the library in detail.

```
npm i needle
```

```js
const needle = require('needle');

needle.get('http://www.example.com', (error, response) => {

  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
    console.log(response.body);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I just gotta figure out how to find just the effects but I'll hopefully be able to do that on my own.